# Looking for an expression that means "I'm at an event right now"

Tags: expressions

Is there any simple and frequently used expression that means "I'm at an event right now", like "I'm here", or "I'm present"?

Comment: You gave two examples; "I'm here" or "I'm present"... both are common.

Comment: 'In attendance' is also somewhat common.

Comment: The more you can tell us about how you want to use the expression, the better the answers you will get. Different responses are appropriate depending on the situation. For example, are you trying to get the attention of other guests who are there? Checking in on a social networking site? Telling someone who is not at the event that you are busy? Trying to be sure the people running the event know that you showed up?

Comment: What aedia said: please explain your context, otherwise we will have to put this on hold as "unclear what you're asking". (For example, you'd say very different things to people also at the same event vs. people elsewhere.)

Answer (score 0):

"I'm indisposed" is a way to say that you're not available (for example, because you're at an event somewhere).

Comment: "I'm indisposed" literally means, and even non-literally at least implies, that you're not feeling well. I'd never ever use it to mean that I'm busy at an event.

Comment: Hmm, I've seen it used in vernacular to mean simply busy (not necessarily at an event) on many occasions.

Comment: I could see it as a sarcastic euphemism (if you know what I mean) for "I'm busy", but it doesn't actually mean that.

Comment: @Marthaª like TylerH, I've seen "I am/will be indisposed" used in speech to mean that the person will be unavailable.  The second definition via Google's dictionary is `averse; unwilling.
"the potential audience seemed indisposed to attend"`, so I can see why, even if it's not strictly correct.

Comment: @Doc, yeah I just looked that up - it's basically "disposed" as in "having a tendency to" plus the negating prefix "in". I can see it having that meaning if you specify the activity ("My mother is indisposed to do the dishes if she cooked dinner"), but *indisposed* on its own ("My mother is indisposed") means illness.

Comment: @Marthaª  "Are you going to the party on Wednesday?"  "No, I'm indisposed."  <- The activity (the party) is implied from context.  The reason for why can be offered, but certainly isn't necessary (and may be considered rude, best to avoid saying "I'd rather not because the host is lame").

Comment: @Doc and Martha, I guess it is normal to say indisposed without meaning ill so long as there is some context suggesting otherwise, whether implied or directly stated?

Comment: @Doc: Unless accompanied by scare quotes/air quotes, I'd still interpret that *indisposed* as "I'm not feeling well". Which begs the question, how do you know on Monday that you're gonna be feeling ill on Wednesday... Bottom line is, I simply wouldn't use this term unless I specifically meant (1) illness, or (2) a general unwillingness (lack of tendency, if you will) to do a specific (and specified!) thing.